# Show that $n^3+2n$ is divisible by 3 for all $n\ge 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

i want to prove it with mathematical induction :

first i am tried with n=0
then it is divisible by zero then i move to next step change all n with K then i get this product :

$$P(K)=K^3+2K = 3m$$

*Note: $3k$ because we multiply any no. with $3$ is divisible by $3$*

now , next step i am increase $+1$ in $k$ so i get this step :

$$(K+1)^3 + 2(K+1) = 3m$$

so now next step i am not able to solve please help.

Comment: $(k+1)^3+2(k+1) = k^3+3k^2+3k+1+2k+2 = (k^3+2k)+3(k^2+k+1)$ is divisible by $3$ because $k^3+2k$ is divisible by $3$ by induction hypothesis.

Comment: Do you know that $(a+b)^3=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Why do you want to prove it by induction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the induction step:

$(n+1)^3+2(n+1)=n^3+2n+3n+3n^2+3=n^3+2n+3(n+n^2+1)$

$n^3+2n$ is divisible by 3 (by assumption) and the last addend is obviusly divisible by 3

**Remark:** If you want to show a statement for all $n\geq k$ then you prove the statement in the first step for k, not for $0$. (In our case we wont get any problems)

Comment: =$$n^3+2n+3(n+n^2+1)$$
=now i put 3m instead of $$n^3+2n$$
so i get $$3m+3(n+n^2+1)$$
now how to simplify this ?

Comment: ...=$3(m+n+n^2+1)$. This number is divisible by 3 (the quotient is $m+n+n^2+1$)

Comment: this is not the answer in answer it must be one variable remain in your case m and n two variable remains so it dosen't proved !

Comment: You defined m, not me. m=n^3+2n, so actually we only have one variable, as you wish...

Comment: no no you get it wrong yes i define m but then we need to simplify  and then remains with one variable 'm' and that's the answer but how that i don't know ?

Answer (score 4):

$$\left((n+1)^3+2(n+1)\right)-\left(n^3+2n\right) = 3(n^2+n+1)$$
is always a multiple of three, hence if $3\mid (n^3+2n)$, then $3\mid ((n+1)^3+2(n+1)).$

Comment: sorry , but i am not able to understand your answer. how you find 3(n^2+n+1) and what do you mean by this symbol '|'

Comment: Expand the LHS. $a\mid b$ means "a divides b", or "b is a multiple of a".

Answer (score 4):

An alternate easier solution: Since $n^3+2n = n(n^2+2) \equiv n(n^2-1) = (n-1)n(n+1) \pmod 3$, for any $n$, either $n$ or $n-1$ or $n+1$ is zero modulo $3$ and so their product is divisible by $3$.

Comment: +1 Much better. Why do people insist on using induction?

Comment: They may do so because there is an integer n and that means induction :-( but in this case the difference between consecutive terms is 3n^2 + 3n + 3 which is _obviously_ divisible by 3 without considering different cases. In the end, you don't know which proof ends up easier until you have done both.

Answer (score 3):

$\begin{eqnarray}{\bf Hint}\ \ \ {\rm mod}\ 3\!:\,\ \color{#0a0}{n^3}\! &\equiv& \color{#c00}n\,\ (\equiv\, -2n)  &&{\rm i.e.}\ \ \ P(n)\\ \Rightarrow\  (n\!+\!1)^3\! &=& \color{#0a0}{n^3}\! + \color{lightgrey}{3n^2\!+3n}\!+\!1\\ &\equiv& \color{#c00}n + 1 && {\rm i.e.}\ \ \ P(n\!+\!1)\end{eqnarray}$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
Lets $\ds{n \equiv 3p + \delta}$ for an integer $\ds{p}$ where $\ds{\delta \in \braces{0,1,2}}$. Then,

> \begin{align}
> n^{3} + 2n&
> =\pars{27p^{3} + 27p^{2}\delta + 9p\delta^{2} + \delta^{3}} + \pars{6p + 2\delta}
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#c00000}{\Large 3}
> \pars{9p^{3} + 9p^{2}\delta + 3p\delta^{2} + 2p}
> +
> \underbrace{\pars{\delta^{3} + 2\delta}}
> _{\ds{\in\ \color{#c00000}{\Large\braces{0,3,12}}}}
> \end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively: $n^3+2n\equiv n^3-n\equiv 0 \pmod 3$, using Fermat's little theorem.

Answer (score 2):

I know you want to prove by induction, but anothter proof would be to observe that every integer is congruent to either 0, 1, or 2 (mod 3). Then we want to see if for every integer n:

$n^3 + 2n \equiv 0\pmod{3}$

Well, take all integers n such that $n \equiv 0\pmod{3}$. Then $n^3 \equiv 0\pmod{3}$ and $2n \equiv 0\pmod{3}$ $\implies n^3 + 2n \equiv 0\pmod{3}$

Take all integers n such that $n \equiv 1\pmod{3}$. Then $n^3 \equiv 1\pmod{3}$ and $2n \equiv 2\pmod{3}$ $\implies n^3 + 2n \equiv 0\pmod{3}$

Take all integers n such that $n \equiv 2\pmod{3}$. Then $n^3 \equiv 2\pmod{3}$ and $2n \equiv 4\equiv1\pmod{3}$ $\implies n^3 + 2n \equiv 0\pmod{3}$

Answer (score 1):

$$it-is--a-proof-without-induction\\\\M=n^3+2n =\\n^3+2n-3n +(3n)\\=n^-n +(3n) \\=n(n^2-1)=(3n)\\=n(n-1)(n+1) +3n \\=3k +3n\\=3(k+n)=3q
$$

Comment: bro, i am doing same like you but at last step it is rule that only one variable remains so what is next step ?